# ASP.NET 5 cross-platform, where would old-fashion DLLs go?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working on test projects using the new (beta) ASP.NET 5.
I have a number of DLLs that need to plugin and as we all know there is no more "bin" folder.
Documentation refers to creating nuget package for these DLLs, I am quite confused about this!

How do you create a nuget package for an existing DLL or is there any other way to references the dlls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `dnu wrap` can be used to wrap non-NuGet assemblies into NuGet packages. It generates a project.json for you, and you can reference it like you would reference any other projects within your solution.

Comment: What would happen to the DLL? where would it go? How do I access the package? Is it publishing it into a server outside of my computer?

Comment: My understanding is that the dlls itself should still contain portable .NET code. Any old fashion DLL won't just run on .NET Core

Comment: @sam360: The DLL lives in the wrapper project directory -- I can't remember the specifics. At runtime, it lives in the nuget package directory, like all other nuget packages.

Comment: @Stilgar: While that's true about .NET Core, it is possible to target the full .NET framework for DNX projects, too, in which case pretty much any old .NET assembly will work, so long as it has a NuGet package.